# Is $\nabla^2(D\nabla^2w) = (\nabla^2 D)(\nabla^2w)+D\nabla^4w $?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

Is $\nabla^2(D\nabla^2w) = (\nabla^2 D)(\nabla^2w)+D\nabla^4w $ ?

or do we getting  some extra terms

$D = D(x,y)$  and $w = w(x,y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Second derivatives obey $(fg)^{\prime\prime}=(f^\prime g+fg^\prime)^\prime=f^{\prime\prime}g+2f^\prime g^\prime+fg^{\prime\prime}$, so in [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)$$\partial_i^2(D\partial_j^2w)=\partial_i^2D\partial_j^2w+2\partial_iD\partial_i\partial_j^2w+D\partial_i^2\partial_j^2w,$$i.e.$$\nabla^2(D\nabla^2w)=(\nabla^2D)(\nabla^2w)+2\nabla D\cdot\nabla(\nabla^2w)+D(\nabla^2)^2w.$$You missed what we call a cross term, but you can write $(\nabla^2)^2$ as $\nabla^4$.